# Ember-Data - Reach Object from Router to Controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

If I do in my router:

```
connectOutlets: function(router, context){
     router.set('objectController.fooObject', App.get("session.sessionObject"));
}
```

How to get this object in my controller? If I initialize it with `object = null,` I can get its attributes with handlebars like this:

```
 {{object.bar}}
```

But  cant get the object in my controller, because if I call a function like this:

```
test: function() {
    console.log(object.bar);
}
```

it wont work. So how to get my context properly in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use getters and setters inside your test function.

```
this.get('foo');
this.set('foo', 'bar')
```

In your case

```
test: function() {
    console.log(this.get('object.bar'));
}
```